# Lubuntu 16.04 - No Network Manager

Tags: wireless, 16.04, lubuntu, network-manager

I recently installed Lubuntu 16.04 on my laptop & I can't seem to get it to connect to WiFi. I tried using the Network Manager but it won't even start.
At first I thought it wasn't installed so I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

The output tells me it's already installed & up to date with the most recent version. I also tried adding "nm-applet" to the Default applications for LXSession on the Autostart tab & rebooting the laptop, but even after that it just doesn't appear on the panel or start with a command from the terminal.
I tried:

```
sudo nm-applet
```

To start it, but the output was:

```
** (nm-applet:20844): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

(nm-applet:20844): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates: assertion 'window->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed
```

The output of:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

was:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: This is not a NM issue. You need to install firmware for your wireless adapter.